# Android: CreateBitmap on onDraw

Tags: android, memory, ondraw

In my custom view I call createBitmap in onDraw method. I have doubts, is it correct to create bitmap on any time in onDraw? 
Any time when onDraw called, I create new bitmap, but what would happen to older one?

Comment: In general it's bad idea. Describe what do you want to do? Frame by frame animation of something another?

Comment: Yes, frame by frame, but user activity can cause of need resize bitmap, therefore i forced recreate bitmap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the way to go:

```
private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Canvas mBitmapCanvas;
private Paint mDrawPaint = new Paint();

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    if (mBitmap == null) {
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        mBitmapCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }

    mBitmapCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE); // clear previously drawn stuff

    // draw stuff...
    mBitmapCanvas.drawLine(....);

    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mDrawPaint);
}
```

You should **avoid, if possible, to allocate memory** (new-operator) inside the `onDraw(Canvas c)` method. However, you can check if your variable has already been created and **avoid re-allocation**.

In order to reset your `Bitmap`, **do not recreate it**, use:

```
mBitmapCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
```

instead.

Comment: user activity can cause of need resize bitmap, therefore i forced recreate bitmap. what if use this variant 
        Bitmap bitmap=this.game.Show();
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
        bitmap.recycle();

Comment: You can recreate the Bitmap via a public method. Just call this method whenever recreation is needed.